# How to get data from curl in REST web service in java?

Tags: java, rest, curl

This is my curl command

```
curl -X PATCH -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "content-type: application/json" -d "{ \"name\": \"guest\" }" --url http://localhost:6080/REST/users/gust.
```

How do I extract the json data `{ name: guest}` from the request. Does the HttpServletRequest class has any supporting method?.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

use Reader:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
    try {
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

or you can try parse the json from the request object using a library, an example is
[org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) which can do this for you quite easily.... here is some sample code to get you started:

```
import org.json.*;

JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(" .... ");
String pageName = obj.getJSONObject("pageInfo").getString("pageName");

JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("posts");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("post_id");
    ......
}
```

Downloadable jar: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json